# Main window event listener doesn't work in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, window, dom-events, mouseevent

I have a kind of resizer that when the user clicked on that an event listener will set to the window object. (actually, main window object not iframe's window. a small part of my program is iframe):

```
const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
}

const handleMouseMove = () => {
  console.log('mouse move')
}

const handleMouseUp = () => {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp)
}
```

When I move the mouse is in the iframe area nothing logs on console. Also, mouse up listener doesn't work when the mouse is in the iframe area.

Actually, I have move complex code in mouse move listener but my problem is that the window event listener doesn't work in the iframe.

I know that iframe has a different window object but I think if there is a way to attach iframe's window to the main window my problem will be solved. I don't know. Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: That's expected. The iframe is a separate document, nothing from the parent window is inherited.

Comment: there is a way to access the parent window in the iframe?

Comment: I'm reading in the MDN iframe page that iframe has its own document but window object is always referred to topmost browsing context that is the parent window object. and I can't find why I can't access the parent window object

Comment: `window.parent` will access the parent.

Comment: Each document has its own `window` variable. `window.parent` is the containing window in the iframe, and `window.top` is the topmost window in the hiearchy.

Comment: so I set an event listener in the parent window like this: window.top.addEve..... but apparently mouse move listener still doesn't work in the iframe. I'm thinking to play with MOMO :)

Comment: you already have a listener in the parent. Events don't bubble up through iframes.

Comment: The parent needs to add an event listener in the iframe: `iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with iframe and found a nice workaround, which however, will definitely not cover all the cases.
In my case I had to resize a unit and, as soon as the cursor goes over the iframe area, main window windowEvent is no longer working, the whole resizing function stops working and even 'mouseup' event is missed. So here the solution which works for me:

```
private _initEvents() {
   $(someElement).on('mousedown', (e) => {
       if (!this._isTransforming) {
           const $iframe = $('.pdf-canvas'); // iframe has pdf-canvas class 
           if ($iframe) $iframe.addClass("no-action"); // the solution itself line #1
           this._transformStart(e);
       }
    });

    windowEvent('mousemove', (e) => {
        if (this._isTransforming) this._transform(e);
    }, this.element);

    windowEvent('mouseup', (e) => {
        if (this._transforming) {
            const $iframe = $('.pdf-canvas');
            if ($iframe) $iframe.removeClass("no-action"); // the solution itself line #2
                this._transformStop(e);
            }
        }
    }, this.element);
}
```

And CSS class:

```
.no-action {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```